# How to pass navigator to the builder property in MaterialApp?

Tags: flutter, dropdown, builder, flutter-getx, navigator

I am using the `builder` property in the `MaterialApp` to have persistent `header` and `footer` all over the app. I am using `GetX`, So I didn't use `GlobalKey` for Navigation.There is a `DropDownButton` to change languages in the `header` and `footer` (Depends on page). Since the `builder` property does not have the `Navigator` from the `MaterialApp`,  It throws an error when I try to open the `DropDownButton`.

**Error:**

```
'Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
```

For now I just wrapped the `MainLayout` with another `MaterialApp`. But it is not a good Solution. Since it's not wise to use two `MaterialApp` in a single project.

How can I solve this issue?

**Main Class:**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await getFlagList();
  await gettingLanguage();
  navigationServiceController.registerLazySingleton(() => NavigationService());
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: "tolk2gotasker", options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  runApp(const Inizilation());
}

class Inizilation extends StatelessWidget {
  const Inizilation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      initialBinding: InitialBinding(),
      title: "T2G Tasker",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        scrollbarTheme: const ScrollbarThemeData(
          thickness: MaterialStatePropertyAll<double>(0),
          trackVisibility: MaterialStatePropertyAll<bool>(false),
          thumbVisibility: MaterialStatePropertyAll<bool>(false),
        ),
        fontFamily: "AvenirLTDStd",
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: kWhite),
        primaryColor: kOrange,
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        applyElevationOverlayColor: true,
        focusColor: Colors.transparent,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: kBlack,
        ),
      ),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale("en", "US"),
        Locale("nl", "NL"),
        Locale('ru', 'RU'),
      ],
      scrollBehavior: RemoveGlowEffect().copyWith(scrollbars: false),
      enableLog: true,
      defaultTransition: Transition.fade,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) =>
          MainLayout(child: child),
      onGenerateInitialRoutes:
          navigationServiceController<NavigationService>().generateInitialRoute,
      onUnknownRoute:
          navigationServiceController<NavigationService>().generateUnknownRoute,
      onGenerateRoute:
          navigationServiceController<NavigationService>().generateRoute,
    );
  }
}
```

**MainLayout:**

```
class MainLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainLayout({super.key, required this.child});

  final Widget? child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        navigationServiceController<NavigationService>().navigateBack();
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: kWhite,
        appBar: const CommonAppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(width: width < 700 ? width : 700, child: child),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const CommonBottomBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**BottomNavigationBar:**

```
class CommonBottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const CommonBottomBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => enableBottomBar.isTrue
          ? ButtonBar(
              alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              buttonAlignedDropdown: true,
              children: [
                const LanguageDropDown(
                  isDense: true,
                  textSize: 14,
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    navigationServiceController<NavigationService>()
                        .taskListPage();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.list,
                    color: commonBottomBarViewModel.selectedIcon[1]
                        ? kOrange
                        : kBlack45,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () =>
                      navigationServiceController<NavigationService>()
                          .notificationPage(),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.notifications_none,
                    color: commonBottomBarViewModel.selectedIcon[2]
                        ? kOrange
                        : kBlack45,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () =>
                      navigationServiceController<NavigationService>()
                          .profilePage(),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person_outline,
                    color: commonBottomBarViewModel.selectedIcon.last
                        ? kOrange
                        : kBlack45,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : const SizedBox.shrink(),
    );
  }
}
```

**LanguageDropDown:**

```
class LanguageDropDown extends GetView {
  const LanguageDropDown({Key? key, this.isDense, this.textSize})
      : super(key: key);

  final bool? isDense;

  final double? textSize;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<LanguageDropDownViewModel>(
      builder: (languageDropDownViewModel) {
        return DropdownButton<Details>(
          value: languageDropDownViewModel.selectedLanguage,
          underline: const SizedBox.shrink(),
          isDense: isDense ?? false,
          onChanged: (Details? language) =>
              languageDropDownViewModel.onchange(language),
          items: kLanguageInfo.map((user) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<Details>(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              value: user,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 15,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      "$baseUrl/${user.flag}",
                    ),
                    onBackgroundImageError: <AssetImage>(context, _) {
                      return Image.asset(
                        kDummyImage,
                        scale: 3,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  CommonText(
                    text: " ${user.code}",
                    textColor: kBlack,
                    size: textSize ?? 16,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Navigation:**

```
class NavigationService {
  Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String routeName) {
    return Get.toNamed(routeName)!;
  }

  Future<dynamic> navigateOffAll(String routeName) {
    return Get.offAllNamed(routeName)!;
  }

  Future<dynamic> navigateUntil(String routeName) {
    return Get.offNamedUntil(routeName, (route) => false)!;
  }

  Future<dynamic> navigateOff(String routeName) {
    return Get.offNamed(routeName)!;
  }

  void navigateBack() {
    switch (Get.currentRoute) {
      case registerScreen:
        navigateOff(emailCheckScreen);
        break;
      case forgotPasswordEmailScreen:
        navigateOff(emailCheckScreen);
        break;
      case forgotPasswordScreen:
        navigateOff(forgotPasswordEmailScreen);
        break;
      case taskDetailsScreen:
        taskListPage();
        break;
      default:
        Get.back();
    }
  }

  void splashScreenPage() {
    navigateTo(splashScreen);
  }

  void emailPage() {
    navigateOffAll(emailCheckScreen);
  }

  void passwordPage() {
    navigateTo(passwordScreen);
  }

  void registerPage() {
    navigateTo(registerScreen);
  }

  void forgotEmailTriggerPage() {
    navigateTo(forgotPasswordEmailScreen);
  }

  void forgotPasswordPage() {
    navigateTo(forgotPasswordScreen);
  }

  void taskListPage() {
    navigateOffAll(taskListScreen);
  }

  void taskDetailsPage() {
    navigateTo(taskDetailsScreen);
  }

  void actualDurationPage() {
    navigateTo(actualDurationScreen);
  }

  void extraAmountPage() {
    navigateTo(extraAmountScreen);
  }

  void signaturePage() {
    navigateTo(signatureScreen);
  }

  void taskComplitionPage() {
    navigateTo(taskCompletionScreen);
  }

  void notificationPage() {
    navigateTo(inAppNotificaitonScreen);
  }

  void profilePage() {
    navigateTo(profileScreen);
  }

  void basicInformationPage() {
    navigateTo(basicInformationScreen);
  }

  void logoutPage() {
    navigateOffAll(logoutScreen);
  }

  Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case splashScreen:
        {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: splashScreen,
            page: () => const SplashScreen(),
            binding: SplashScreenBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }

      case passwordScreen:
        {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: passwordScreen,
            page: () => const PasswordPage(),
            binding: LoginBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case registerScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = kLanguage.value.register;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: registerScreen,
            page: () => const AccountRegister(),
            binding: LoginBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case forgotPasswordEmailScreen:
        {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: forgotPasswordEmailScreen,
            page: () => const ForgotEmailTrigger(),
            binding: LoginBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case forgotPasswordScreen:
        {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: forgotPasswordScreen,
            page: () => const ForgotEmailTriggerConfirmation(),
            binding: LoginBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case taskListScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = "";
          enableAppBar.value = true;
          enableBottomBar.value = true;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: taskListScreen,
            page: () => const TaskListPage(),
            binding: TaskListBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case taskDetailsScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value =
              commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: taskDetailsScreen,
            page: () => const TaskDetailsPage(),
            binding: TaskDetailsBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case actualDurationScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value =
              commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: actualDurationScreen,
            page: () => const ActualDuration(),
            binding: ActualDurationBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case extraAmountScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value =
              commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: extraAmountScreen,
            page: () => const ExtraAmount(),
            binding: ExtraAmountBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case signatureScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value =
              commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: signatureScreen,
            page: () => const Signature(),
            binding: SignatureBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case taskCompletionScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value =
              commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: taskCompletionScreen,
            page: () => const TaskComplition(),
            binding: TaskCompletionBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case inAppNotificaitonScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = "";
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: inAppNotificaitonScreen,
            page: () => const InAppNotification(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case profileScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = "";
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: profileScreen,
            page: () => const ProfilePage(),
            binding: ProfileBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case basicInformationScreen:
        {
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = "";
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: basicInformationScreen,
            page: () => const BasicInformation(),
            binding: ProfileBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      case logoutScreen:
        {
          prefs.clear();
          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = "";
          commonBottomBarViewModel.taskerName.value = "";
          enableBottomBar.value = false;
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: logoutScreen,
            page: () => const LogoutPage(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
      default:
        {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: emailCheckScreen,
            page: () => const EmailCheck(),
            binding: LoginBinding(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
    }
  }

  Route<dynamic> generateUnknownRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = "";
    enableAppBar.value = true;
    kLoginStatus = prefs.getBool("loginStatus") ?? false;
    if (kLoginStatus) {
      enableBottomBar.value = true;
      return GetPageRoute(
        routeName: taskListScreen,
        page: () => const TaskListPage(),
        binding: TaskListBinding(),
        settings: settings,
      );
    } else {
      return GetPageRoute(
        routeName: emailCheckScreen,
        page: () => const EmailCheck(),
        binding: LoginBinding(),
        settings: settings,
      );
    }
  }

  List<Route<dynamic>> generateInitialRoute(String initialPage) {
    kLoginStatus = prefs.getBool("loginStatus") ?? false;
    if (kIsWeb) {
      if (kLoginStatus) {
        enableAppBar.value = true;
        enableBottomBar.value = true;
        return [
          GetPageRoute(
            routeName: taskListScreen,
            page: () => const TaskListPage(),
            binding: TaskListBinding(),
            settings: const RouteSettings(name: taskListScreen),
          )
        ];
      } else {
        enableAppBar.value = true;
        return [
          GetPageRoute(
            routeName: emailCheckScreen,
            page: () => const EmailCheck(),
            binding: LoginBinding(),
            settings: const RouteSettings(name: emailCheckScreen),
          )
        ];
      }
    } else {
      return [
        GetPageRoute(
          routeName: splashScreen,
          page: () => const SplashScreen(),
          binding: SplashScreenBinding(),
          settings: const RouteSettings(name: splashScreen),
        )
      ];
    }
  }

  void redirectingToTaskDetailsPage() {
    if (Get.previousRoute == "/") {
      commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value = commonBottomBarViewModel.bookingId;
      taskDetailsPage();
    }
  }
}
```

**AppBar:**

```
class CommonAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  const CommonAppBar({super.key});

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(Get.height * 0.07);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Obx(
      () => enableAppBar.isTrue
          ? ScreenTypeLayout.builder(
              mobile: (BuildContext context) => AppBar(
                centerTitle: false,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
                elevation: 0,
                titleSpacing: 0,
                backgroundColor: kWhite,
                leadingWidth: commonBottomBarViewModel.title.isNotEmpty
                    ? null
                    : width * 0.3,
                leading: Obx(
                  () => commonBottomBarViewModel.title.isNotEmpty
                      ? IconButton(
                          onPressed: () =>
                              navigationServiceController<NavigationService>()
                                  .navigateBack(),
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back,
                            color: kBlack,
                          ),
                        )
                      : Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            kLogoImage,
                            scale: 2.5,
                            semanticLabel: "Tolk2Go Icon",
                          ),
                        ),
                ),
                title: Obx(
                  () => CommonText(
                    text: commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value,
                  ),
                ),
                actions: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Obx(
                      () => enableBottomBar.isFalse
                          ? const LanguageDropDown()
                          : CommonText(
                              text: commonBottomBarViewModel.taskerName.value,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              desktop: (BuildContext context) => AppBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
                elevation: 0,
                titleSpacing: 0,
                leadingWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: kWhite,
                title: SizedBox(
                  width: width * 0.75,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Obx(
                        () => commonBottomBarViewModel.title.isNotEmpty
                            ? Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () =>
                                        navigationServiceController<
                                                NavigationService>()
                                            .navigateBack(),
                                    icon: const Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_back,
                                      color: kBlack,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Obx(
                                    () => CommonText(
                                      text:
                                          commonBottomBarViewModel.title.value,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            : Image.asset(
                                kLogoImage,
                                scale: 2.5,
                                semanticLabel: "Tolk2Go Icon",
                              ),
                      ),
                      Obx(
                        () => enableBottomBar.isFalse
                            ? const LanguageDropDown()
                            : CommonText(
                                text: commonBottomBarViewModel.taskerName.value,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : const SizedBox.shrink(),
    );
  }
}
```